# Condensed Mob Names in Scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using this command to add a scoreboard so that the health of a mob can be seen:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Zombie,name=Joe] bossHealth 100
```

And I want it to come up on the scoreboard as

> Joe        100

But instead it shows up as

> 0fb6ee26-3210-45b2-8043-ecab01afe679 100

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: I think not.. That's the zombie's UUID , the ID which makes the zombie unique . The scoreboard works by the UUIDs of the entities

Comment: @iDoomfull Actually there is a workaround, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is indeed a way to bypass this. First of all, create another scoreboard objective that will be used as the dummy objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add bossHealth_1 dummy
```

Now place a repeating command block containing the following command:

```
/scoreboard players operation Joe bossHealth = @e[type=Zombie,name=Joe] bossHealth_1
```

Keep the `bossHealth` objective in the sidebar as a scoreboard. Then, every time that you want to change the `bossHealth` objective, change the `bossHealth_1` objective instead and the `bossHealth` objective wil change automatically.

This is because the scoreboard operations command will change the first entity's specific score (the `Joe bossHealth` part) according to the second entity's other specific score (the `@e[type=Zombie,name=Joe] bossHealth_1` part), by the operation provided (the `=` part)

For more about the scoreboard operations command, [click here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Command_reference) and scroll to the bottom of the table.

Comment: I followed steps, but sidebar still shows the numerical UUID

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice It works for me. Did you reset the Zombie's score of `bossHealth`?

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice Also remember to keep the original `bossHealth` objective in the sidebar.

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice This one works for me also

Comment: Okay , let me try to start from scratch, I was trying to implement this into an existing system. Will accept answer if works :)

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice No problem, glad it worked for you :D