# Testing For A Mob With Less than "x" Hearts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a boss battle, and the boss has a few different stages already implemented, I just need a detector to tell the stages when to activate. To activate the final stage, I want the mob to have less than 20 half hearts, and I try to test that with this command:

```
/testfor @e[type=Zombie,name=Joe,score_bossHealth_min=1,score_bossHealth_max=20]
```

However it does not seem to find the mob. In case I'm changing the wrong thing, [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272550/condensed-mob-names-in-scoreboard) refers to the only other variable that could be affected/affect the mob. Did I make an error in the syntax?

Comment: What is the type of the `bossHealth` objective?

Comment: It is dummy type @CommandFox

Comment: Then the problem is that the the type has to be `health` not `dummy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to detect health the type of the objective should be `health` and not `dummy`.

Second of all, there is an error in the syntax. You cannot use `score_bossHealth_max` in your selector arguments, it is invalid. To select something by a maximum score just use `score_bossHealth` and don't add `_min` or `_max`:

```
/testfor @e[type=Zombie,name=Joe,score_bossHealth_min=1,score_bossHealth=20]
```

Comment: The testfor command is not working, and Joe's health is not being displayed on the scoreboard, do I have to set it manually?

Comment: Note I changed bossHealth to type health

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice If Joe's health is not displayed on the scoreboard, it means his health is full, I think.

Comment: Even after dealing damage joes health did not appear @CommandFox

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you made an error in the syntax. `score_health_max` in an invalid argument. Use `score_health` instead:

```
/testfor @e[type=Zombie,name=Joe,score_bossHealth_min=1,score_bossHealth=20]
```

That should work.
Also, you can (if you don't have another Joe) remove the `type=Zombie`.

Comment: I'm using a wither called Joe to make a custom mob bar, so type=Zombie is needed ;)